# how to make lines cross in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm very early in making a simple graph to plot the temperature and humidity of a given space however, the graph plots both lines but they don't intersect instead they do something like in the image below:
[image]

here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import count
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import serial
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

x = []

line1 = []
line2 = []

serialPort = serial.Serial(port = "COM3", baudrate=115200,
                           bytesize=8, timeout=1, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

serialString = ""

index = count()
 

def animate(i):
    
    if serialPort.in_waiting > 0:
        serialString = serialPort.readline()
        string = serialString.decode('Ascii') 
        
        line1.append(string.split(' ')[0])
        line2.append(string.split(' ')[1])
        
        x.append(next(index))
        print(len(line1))
        
        if len(line1) >= 1000:
            line1.pop(0)
            line2.pop(0)
            x.pop(0)


    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(x, line1, label='Temperature')
    plt.plot(x, line2, label='Humidity')



ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=400)
 

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the desired output/outcome?

Comment: @UmbertoFontanazza  I want the orange line to be able to go down further instead of when it gets close to the blue line it goes up instead of down which makes the graph confusing.

Comment: That doesn't depent on pyplot, it depends on the values you are plotting

Comment: So is this because there is too big of a difference in the lines that they won't intersect because of that. If so, is there any way to change that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to plot on two different axis in order to span the whole figure for both curve?

Comment: That's a great way to solve the problem, thankyou for your help!

Comment: Also, I believe you are plotting the string values. That's why your y-axis is not sorted and not following a scale. Better convert the `line1` and `line2` elements to float.

Comment: Finding the intersection of two curves is not pointless only when the two curves represent the same thing, ⁰C and ⁰C, apples and apples, value of apples in € and value of bananas in €.